# How can I use Terraform Cloud to manage itself?

Tags: terraform

I created this simple example:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.0"
  required_providers {
    tfe = {
      source  = "hashicorp/tfe"
      version = "~> 0.40"
    }
  }
  cloud {
    organization = "myorg"
    workspaces {
      name = "test-management"
    }
  }
}

resource "tfe_workspace" "test" {
  organization = "myorg"
  name         = "test"
}
```

When I run the `init` command, it creates the `test-management` workspace as expected. The problem is that when I run the `apply` I get this error:

```
│ Error: Error creating workspace test for organization myorg: resource not found
│ 
│   with tfe_workspace.test,
│   on main.tf line 17, in resource "tfe_workspace" "test":
│   17: resource "tfe_workspace" "test" {
```

Is it impossible to have Terraform Cloud manage its resources?

Answer (score 0):

It's a must to define the API token. At first, I thought it would be done automatically by Terraform Cloud, but it isn't.

You can set the `token` variable in the `provider "tfe" {}` or the `TFE_TOKEN` environment variable. I recommend the environment variable using the sensitive mode so you don't leak the API token.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming that the problem is credentials-related due to the other existing answer.)

The `hashicorp/tfe` provider is (like all providers) a separate plugin program from Terraform itself, but it supports mostly the same methods for searching for credentials that Terraform CLI does.

If you use one of the following options then the credentials will work across both Terraform CLI and the `hashicorp/tfe` provider at the same time:

1. Run [`terraform login`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/login) to generate a credentials file for the host `app.terraform.io` (Terraform Cloud's hostname) in your home directory.
2. Set the environment variable `TF_TOKEN_app_terraform_io` to an existing Terraform Cloud API token. Terraform CLI and `hashicorp/terraform` both treat this environment variable as equivalent to a credentials configuration like what `terraform login` would create.

(You only need to do *one* of these things; they all achieve a similar result.)